# Migrate data from MySQL to Google App Engine (Python) Data Store

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a legacy website created in PHP and MySQL. I wish to migrate this onto Google App Engine (Python).

Has anybody done this before? Any examples, tips, resources, tools you'd like to share?

I believe I will have to use "bulkloader" introduced in the GAE docs. Still haven't figured out how to get started.

I have two tasks:

1. Migrate from MySQL DB to local GAE App data store
2. Convert from MySQL -> CSV/XML -> Production data store

Help will be appreciated! :-)

--Sri

Comment: Do not overlook the fact that your MySQL tables will not import directly into the datastore in a way that will allow you to use the datastore as it is intended. The datastore is non-relational, and without some reorganization of the data, you are likely to end up with serious performance problems. That's not for certain of course, but it is very likely.

Comment: @Adam, Yes. I've taken that into consideration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GAE now supports PHP (experimental) and CloudSQL  which is very similar to MYSQL. I am currently writing a few testing apps. You can try to apply here.

To enable your PHP applications to be deployed to App Engine, visit https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/ to register your application to be whitelisted

Try from a regular gmail account.

Comment: Three years too late? :) ... Anyway I moved my app to GAE and then left GAE because of technology lock-ins and opaque payment system.

Comment: Hi Srirangan,
I was looking to migrate MySQL to Google App Engine (Python-django) Data Store and landed here. Can you please share the steps you have followed for the migration. Any tutorial, links can be helpful. Thanks !